# Conexão Python com SQL Anywhere 16 falha

Tags: sql, python, sybase

Olá!

Estou tentando conectar o Python com um banco de dados do Sybase mas todas as formas que eu tento, acaba dando esse erro.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\yuri.mendonca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\dominio_connection.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};' pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL
>   Anywhere]Database server not found (-100) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Meu código está como:

```
import pyodbc  conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Anywhere 16};'
                      'Server=***.**.**.***;'
                      'Database=*********;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor() cursor.execute('select...')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Já utilizei o mesmo código pra conectar em um banco de dados do SQL Server e consegui sem problemas, pra conectar com um banco de dados SQL Anywhere não está indo.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Certificou-se que o `Database` informado existe no servidor?

Comment: Tenta com um restart do serviço.

Answer (score -2):

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Anywhere 16};'
                      'DSN="";'
                      'UID="";'
                      'PWD="";'
                      'DatabaseName="";'
                      'ServerName="";'
                      'AutoStop=YES;'
                      'Integrated=NO;'
                      'host="";'
                      'serverport="";'
                      'Description=""')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "you table" ")
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Complementando o comentário do Bot acima, o ideal é dar respostas que expliquem o que está sendo feito, pois só respondendo com o código que resolve o problema a pessoa que está com dúvida acaba aprendendo muito menos.